# istio new installation causing readinees probe failed

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks, readinessprobe

I am installing istio version 1.1.5 on Azure kubernetes services. i have followed the installation procedure mentioned in this istio site [isito installation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/helm/#option-1-install-with-helm-via-helm-template)

I have installed istio-demo installation pack. after successful installation,few resources are not starting...

```
NAME                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-6b849f66c8-hfn24                  1/1       Running            0          10h
istio-citadel-6f958bff99-r4jdj            1/1       Running            0          10h
istio-galley-64867c7ddc-jggxx             1/1       Running            0          10h
istio-grafana-post-install-1.1.5-8mstl    0/1       Completed          0          10h
istio-ingressgateway-5f9765f889-gpvt2     0/1       Running            0          10h
istio-init-crd-10-8s7ng                   0/1       Completed          0          10h
istio-init-crd-11-jdgrd                   0/1       Completed          0          10h
istio-pilot-ff9d76fd8-5zz89               1/2       Running            0          10h
istio-policy-6d5fff9559-qdgqw             1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   225        10h
istio-sidecar-injector-847bcc5744-lgtzd   1/1       Running            0          10h
istio-telemetry-795546db77-sqr5j          1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   221        10h
istio-tracing-595796cf54-x78qr            1/1       Running            0          10h
kiali-5c584d45f6-q54kw                    1/1       Running            0          10h
prometheus-5fffdf8848-7ddkw               1/1       Running            0          10h
```

when i checked the pod description of  `istio-ingressgateway-5f9765f889-gpvt2`, I am getting below error..

> Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503

similarly for other pod `istio-telemetry-795546db77-sqr5j` , I am getting below error.

> Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.40.226.41:15014/version: dial
>   tcp 10.40.226.41:15014: connect: connection refused

I  have enabled `rewriteAppHTTPProbe=true` but no luck..

Comment: hm, try deleting crds and start from scratch? it works fine for me with 1.1.6

Comment: getting same issue after updating to 1.1.6 version

Comment: You can take a look at the [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/11526).

Comment: just install from scratch. demo install works fine

Comment: it is not working on azure kubernetes services

Comment: it does :) I have several aks instances with istio

Answer (score 0):

Same issue was already discussed [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7675#issuecomment-415447894)

Istio is overwhelming the API server on startup.

To fix it you need to add `--useAdapterCRDs=false` to the args of the mixer container in the policy_container and telemetry_container sections.